# How to style a table using the Google Fusion Tables php api?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm slowly figuring out how to use bits and pieces of the v1 api, so far I can successfully authenticate using a service account, list and create tables and manipulate table permissions.  I'm currently trying to style a table programmatically and I'm getting 400 bad request back from the server.  It is really not clear to me how to generate a valid request for styling, the docs are not clear at all.  My table contains only polylines and I would like the color and weight to come from two specific columns.

This is my code:

```
$resp = $fusionTables->style->insert($id, new Google_StyleSetting(array(
  "polylineOptions"=> new Google_LineStyle(array(
    "strokeColorStyler" => new Google_StyleFunction(array(
      "kind" => "fromColumn",
      "columnName" => "color"
  )),
  "strokeWeightStyler"=> new Google_StyleFunction(array(
    "kind" => "fromColumn",
    "columnName" => "width"
    ))
  )),
  "isDefaultForTable" => false
  ))
);
```

In the [using the API documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#CreatingStyle), it seems reasonable that I would only need to provide the polylineOptions with the two stylers.  This is somewhat inconsistent with the [reference api documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/style/insert) which seems to indicate that there are 6 required parameters to specify the column name for all the possible stylers, which seems wrong.  In any case, I did attempt a version that configured points, lines and polygons with stylers as indicated by the reference docs and got nowhere.  I also tried supplying other optional values including a style name and tableId.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was closer than I thought.  Re-reading the documentation carefully, it seems that the "kind" property for a styler must `fusiontables#fromColumn` instead of just `fromColumn`.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent PHP client library v2.0 has renamed the classes.  So the code now becomes:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('oauth-credentials.json');
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables");

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) 
{
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);  
    $service = new Google_Service_Fusiontables($client);
} 

$tableId = "{enter_your_table_id}";

$style = $service->style->insert($tableId, new Google_Service_Fusiontables_StyleSetting(array(
        'markerOptions' => new Google_Service_Fusiontables_PointStyle(array(
            "iconStyler" => new Google_Service_Fusiontables_StyleFunction(array(
                "kind" => "fusiontables#fromColumn",
                "columnName" => "markerColor"
            ))
        )),
        'polylineOptions' => new Google_Service_Fusiontables_LineStyle(array(
            "strokeColorStyler" => new Google_Service_Fusiontables_StyleFunction(array(
                "kind" => "fusiontables#fromColumn",
                "columnName" => "polylineStrokeColor"
            )),
            "strokeWeightStyler"=> new Google_Service_Fusiontables_StyleFunction(array(
                "kind" => "fusiontables#fromColumn",
                "columnName" => "polylineStrokeWeight"
            ))
        )),
        'polygonOptions' => new Google_Service_Fusiontables_PolygonStyle(array(
            "fillColorStyler" => new Google_Service_Fusiontables_StyleFunction(array(
                "kind" => "fusiontables#fromColumn",
                "columnName" => "polygonFillColor"
            )),
            "strokeColorStyler" => new Google_Service_Fusiontables_StyleFunction(array(
                "kind" => "fusiontables#fromColumn",
                "columnName" => "polylineStrokeColor"
            )),
            "strokeWeightStyler"=> new Google_Service_Fusiontables_StyleFunction(array(
                "kind" => "fusiontables#fromColumn",
                "columnName" => "polylineStrokeWeight"
            ))
        )),
        "isDefaultForTable" => true
        ))
    );
```

More information can be found here:
(1) **[Creating a style](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/using#CreatingStyle)**
(2) **[Reference](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/style)**